# Processing form-required-fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, input

I can´t figure out how to edit this code in order to get all cotegories (dropdown-list-fields) being required fields. This script only validates up to 2 dropdown-list-fields before being processed and I have up to 4 categories dropdown-list-fields. Any ideas?

```
<!-- category select -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?= FORM::label('category', __('Category'), array('for'=>'category'))?>
                    <div id="category-chained" class="row <?=($id_category === NULL) ? NULL : 'hidden'?>"
                        data-apiurl="<?=Route::url('api', array('version'=>'v1', 'format'=>'json', 'controller'=>'categories'))?>"
                        data-price0="<?=i18n::money_format(0)?>"
                        <?=(core::config('advertisement.parent_category')) ? 'data-isparent' : NULL?>
                    >
                        <div id="select-category-template" class="col-md-5 hidden">
                            <select class="disable-chosen select-category" placeholder="<?=__('Pick a category...')?>"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div id="paid-category" class="col-md-12 hidden">
                            <span class="help-block" data-title="<?=__('Category %s is a paid category: %d')?>"><span class="text-warning"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?if($id_category !== NULL):?>
                        <div id="category-edit" class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<?=$selected_category->name?>" disabled>
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><?=__('Select another')?></button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?endif?>
                    <input id="category-selected" name="category" value="<?=$id_category?>" class="form-control invisible" style="height: 0; padding:0; width:1px; border:0;" required></input>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Using HTML5 all you have to do is add the `required` property to each input or select.

Comment: If you POST the data, what do you see in the POST array? Without looking at your code too closely, I also see that there is a disabled control

<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<?=$selected_category->name?>" disabled>

Form data in a disabled control will not be POSTed

Comment: If by *"required fields"* you mean no form is submitted unless its fields are filled with anything, then is `required` property you want.

Comment: I did that but it does not validate all of them!